# Slight lag when typing on Big Sur vs Catalina?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, big-sur

I'm using a 2019 Macbook pro. The specs are:

2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9

32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

I recently upgraded from Catalina to Big Sur (v 11.6), and I notice the experience, especially when typing, isn't as smooth as when I had Catalina.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. The best would be to start by doing a safe boot, in order to empty the system caches and if the phenomenon continues, you can scan your Mac with Etrecheck.

Comment: I would also create a brand new user account and test the problem there. If it works as expected, then you know it's not the OS that is the cause, but something else, like software you've installed or some preference setting.

Comment: Take a look at the Activity Monitor utility to see if the computer is busier than you expect it to be, and if so why.  benwiggy's suggestion is also excellent.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem on mbp 16' 2019 and
searched solution for 4+ months.
Helped only switching to eGPU.

Big sur & Monterey not optimized for Intel UHD Graphics 630.
switch to eGPU or buy new mac.

Comment: I have a 2018 Mini with the same Intel UHD 630 graphics unit, and I've not noticed any problem typing. Suggesting "buy a new Mac" is a bit extreme without further analysis.